# Proving inequality by induction only

Tags: inequality, induction

Suppose $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are real positive numbers s.t. $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i=1$. My book claims that by induction only (i.e. **the use of AM-GM is forbidden**), one can prove that $$\sum a_i\ge n$$ and that equiality exists if and only if $\forall i,a_i=1$. I tried to prove it:

for $n=2,$ denote $a_1=a,a_2=\frac 1 a$ then: $$0\le \frac{(a-1)^2}{a}=a+\frac{1}{a}-2\Rightarrow a_1+a_2\ge 2.$$

Now we need to prove it for $n+1$. Denote by $b_n=a_na_{n+1}$, By hypothesis $$a_1\cdots a_{n-1} b_n=1\Rightarrow a_1+\dots a_{n-1}+b_n\ge n$$ which means $$a_1+\dots+a_{n-1}+a_n +a_{n+1} \ge n-b_n+a_n+a_{n+1}.$$ That means I need to prove $$a_n+a_{n+1}-a_na_{n+1}\ge 1$$ but I don't know how.

How can I complete the proof?

Comment: Just a note, writing $0\leq (a-b)^2$ (which is in principle the $n=2$ step) is (no surprise) equivalent to $ab\leq\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$, i.e. the arithmetic-geometric inequality. I guess the important thing here is not to use arithmetic-geometric inequality directly in the general step.

Comment: When proving for $n+1$, first do the following: because the product of the variables is $1$, there must exist at least one variable $\ge 1$ and one $\le 1$ (otherwise the variables will be either all > 1 or all < 1 and thus their product cannot be 1). Without loss of generality (since the role of the variables are the same), suppose that $a_n \ge 1$ and $a_{n+1}\le 1$. Then we have $(1-a_n)(1-a_{n+1})\le 0$, equivalent to $a_n+a_{n+1}- a_na_{n+1}\ge 1$. Now applying the inequality for $n$ numbers we have...etc...

Answer (score 2):

The inequality you need to prove (I think you should change the $n-1$ to $n+1$ if you follow what you have on the previous line),
$$
a_n+a_{n+1}-a_na_{n+1}\geq 1
$$
is not in general true. Take $a_n=a_{n+1}=2$ (which is perfectly valid). This gives zero in the left-hand side.

So, maybe what you can do, is to assume that you, in your product $b_n=a_na_{n+1}$ choose the elements $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ that has a certain property?

Comment: Why such elements exist?

Comment: Say that you, among the numbers $a_1$, $\cdots$, $a_{n+1}$ with product one were unlucky to have $a_n=2$ and $a_ {n+1}=2$. Then, you must also have other elements that are strictly less than one. The only thing I meant in my answer, is that maybe you can find $a_j$ and $a_k$ in your list such that $a_j+a_k-a_ja_k\geq 1$. Do you agree that it would be sufficient?

Comment: My answer shows that you do not need to assume any of the $a_i$ have any special relation to $1$.

Comment: That'd be sufficient but I'm not sure how can I pick these $a_j,a_k$. I assume they have to be both $\le 1$ but how to continue?

Comment: @mickep  Albeit it's trivial but can you please explain why one doesn't have to assume any relation of $a_i$ to 1(in sake of completeness)?

Comment: @Flaring Joe make some effort to clarify the relation $a_j + a_k - a_j a_k \geqslant 1$then you will know which $a_j$ and $a_k$ to pick.

Comment: @Nir I don't understand your comment. If you want to add something to my answer, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n+a_{n+1}-a_na_{n+1}\ge 1 \Leftrightarrow 1 - a_n -a_{n+1} + a_na_{n+1} \le 0. $$

Factorize the LHS and you will see which $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ you should pick.

Answer (score 0):

What we want to show is that
$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i=1
\implies \sum a_i\ge n
$.

This is certainly true for $n=1$.

Suppose it is true for $n$.

Suppose we have
$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i=1
$.
We want to show that
$ \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i\ge n+1
$.

As a first try,
let's look at
$\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i
$.
If
$A
=(\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i)^{1/n}
$
and
$b_i
=a_i/A
$,
then
$\prod_{i=1}^{n} b_i
= 1
$,
so
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i
\ge n
$,
or
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i
\ge An
$.
Therefore
$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i
\ge An+a_{n+1}
$.

If we can show that
$ An+a_{n+1}
\ge n+1
$, we are done.

This is the same as
$\frac{An+a_{n+1}}{n+1}
\ge 1
$.
But
$1
=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i
=a_{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i
=a_{n+1}A^n
$,
so this is the same as
$\frac{An+a_{n+1}}{n+1}
\ge a_{n+1}A^n
$
or
$An+a_{n+1}
\ge (n+1)a_{n+1}A^n
$
or
$An+1/A^n
\ge (n+1)a_{n+1}A^n
$

By the AM-GM means inequality,
since $nA$ is $n$ copies of $A$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{ An+a_{n+1}}{n+1}
&\ge \sqrt[n]{A^n a_{n+1}}\\
&= \sqrt[n]{(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i) a_{n+1}}\\
&= \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i}\\
&= 1\\
\end{array}
$

and,
to my pleasant surprise,
we are done.

(added even later)

We are not allowed to use
the AM-GM inequality.
However,
I will now show,
based on some earlier work of my own,
that this particular use
on the AM-GM inequality,
in which all but one of the values
are equal,
is a consequence of
Bernoulli's inequality.

Bernoulli's inequality,
which is easily proved by induction,
states that
$(1+x)^m \ge 1+mx
$
if $x \ge 0$ and
$m$ is a positive integer
with equality if and only if
$m = 1$
or
$x = 0$.

Therefore
$(1+\frac{v/u-1}{m})^m 
\ge 1+m\frac{v/u-1}{m} 
= \frac{v}{u}
$ with
equality only if 
$m=1$ or $v/u-1 = 0
$,
which is the same as 
$v = u$.
Multiplying by $u^m$,
this becomes

$\begin{array}\\
u^{m-1}v
&\le u^m(1+\frac{v/u-1}{m})^m \\
&= (u+\frac{v-u}{m})^m \\
&= (\frac{v+(m-1)u}{m})^m \\
\text{or}\\
(u^{m-1}v)^{1/m}
&\le \frac{v+(m-1)u}{m}\\
\end{array}
$

But this is just
the AM-GM inequality
with all but one of the values equal!

Therefore,
this use of the
AM-GM inequality
is OK to use,
since it is a consequence
of Bernoulli's inequality,
not the full
AM-GM inequality.

(added later)

If there is equality,
then
$A = a_{n+1}
$.
Since
$1 
=A^n a_{n+1}
$,
$1 = a^{n+1}_{n+1}
$,
so
$a_{n+1} = 1$.
This implies that
there is equality for
$n$,
so that
$a_n = 1$.
This allows us to
work our way back down
in an odd kind of
inverse induction
to show that
equality at *any* step
shows that
at that step
and all preceding steps
$a_i = 1$.

This is weird,
but I think that
it is correct.

Comment: nice but I cannot use the AM-GM in this proof as mickep indicated in his comment above.

Comment: I'll see if I can fix it. I have an idea.

Comment: I fixed it, based on some earlier work of mine.

Comment: That's the case of equality in the AM-GM inequality - all the terms are equal and they consist of $n$ $A$s and one $a_{n+1}$.